# What are these Star Wars Lego figures supposed to be?

Tags: star-wars, object-identification, lego, lego-star-wars

[image]

My guess is they're pod racers....

Comment: Are those even official LEGO designs or something "custom"?

Comment: @jwodder it is likely they are custom; I found them among things ready to go into a garage sale. I assumed they were at least partly Star Wars-inspired since they ended up in a 2011 Star Wars December calendar.

Comment: It probably would have helped to mention in the question that these were part of an official Advent calendar.

Comment: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/ would have probably been a better place for this question.

Comment: @Morgan: Either they are "custom designs" (i.e. not designed by LEGO), or they are part of a Star Wars advent calendar produced by LEGO, right?

Comment: Your middle ship is definitely assembled incorrectly. You can find instructions online, now that you know what it is.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As suggested by @Thunderforge in the comment below, these appear to be from the [2011 *Lego Star Wars* Advent Calendar](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/7958_Star_Wars_Advent_Calendar):

The Yellow one is a [Y-Wing fighter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/BTL%20Y-wing%20starfighter)

My best guess for the grey and white one is a [T-47 Airspeeder](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/T-47_airspeeder) (Snowspeeder)

The Red one looks like a [CR20 Troop Carrier](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/CR20_troop_carrier) seen in the Clone Wars animated series:

[image]

The Advent Calendar Manifest on Brickpedia says that all of those craft were included in the Advent Calendar.  In fact, if you look at the below image, you  will see there was a Y-Wing fighter, a Corvette and a Snowspeeder.

[image]

The reason the Snowspeeder was so difficult to identify it seems is because we are looking at the back of it!

Comment: @Morgan you're welcome. I'll add some pictures in a little while 

Comment: There was a snow speeder in the [2011 Star Wars Calendar](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/7958_Star_Wars_Advent_Calendar) where the others are from. There is no picture on the wiki, but that seems like the correct call.

Comment: "The reason the Snowspeeder was so difficult to identify it seems is because we are looking at the back of it!" - not only that. When you compare your image of the snowspeeder with that by the OP, you'll notice that a black [grille part](http://media.peeron.com/ldraw/images/7/2412b.png) has been added to the front of the snowspeeder.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Not only that, there's also a piece on the back behind the cockpit that is missing in the OP's image.  The second window piece sloping to the back would have to be removed for it to fit there though.

Comment: Isn't the yellow one supposed to be a [Naboo N-1 fighter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/N-1_starfighter)?

Comment: @Martha that is a reasonable interpretation, but as the others are from the advent calendar, and that had a Y-Wing in it but not a Naboo fighter (the picture of the Advent calendar proves that) I'm still quite confident that it's a Y-Wing

Comment: I am pretty convinced that the red one is a republic cruiser, as seen at the beginning of The Phantom Menace : http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Consular-class_Space_Cruiser

Comment: @O.R.Mapper thank you for your observations- what changes I could make to the snowspeeder have been made, and it is now recognizable :)

Comment: thank you for your observations- what changes I could make to the snowspeeder have been made, and it is now recognizable :) @DarrelHoffman

Comment: Again, I'd like to thank you, @N_Soong , for your very thorough answer!

Answer (score 4):

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Consular-class_cruiser

It's not a CR20 troop carrier but rather a consular class cruser I think. (From the Episode I, at the very beginning)