# What is this Star Wars LEGO figure?

Tags: star-wars, object-identification, lego, lego-star-wars

[image: Unknown Lego figure]

What is this? Found it in an old Star Wars advent calendar. Not sure if it's custom or official, and I will appreciate any good guesses.

Comment: It’s a [headcrab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headcrab).

Comment: Here, as in [your other question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115225/what-are-these-star-wars-lego-figures-supposed-to-be/115228), be aware that people who see this as a Lego-question related to Star Wars will interpret "custom or official" as "built by people unrelated to LEGO" vs. "designed by LEGO", whereas people who see this as a Star Wars question related to LEGO will interpret "custom or official" as "designed by Star Wars fans" vs. "modelled after something in Star Wars canon". You may want to clarify the respective terms.

Comment: FYI, there is SE network for Lego and friend: [bricks.se]

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Well, it turns out it's "official" in both senses, so it didn't end up making a difference.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is a fairly easy item to find using the resources of [BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com/index.asp), which is designed for finding parts/inventories (and also buying/selling LEGO items).

The primary part to search for is the leg piece, which LEGO calls the `Bad Robot Arm` and BrickLink calls the `[Arm Mechanical, Exo-Force / Bionicle][2]`.

After finding that part (by searching "Arm Mechanical", but "arm" would have brought you to it eventually), you see this information on the page:

> **Appears In**
> 136 Sets
> 28 Minifigs
> 2 Books
> 3 Gear

Click the [136 Sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=53989&in=S) link shows me every set that part has been in. But, we don't want *every set*, so I just did a quick search in the window using CTRL-F for "Star Wars".

Once it reached the "Reddish Brown" color section, which matches your photo, I saw that it matched the picture for:

### **Advent Calendar 2011, Star Wars (Day 3) - Mechno-Chair**.

[image]

So, this is an officially licensed *Star Wars* product, of an actual item from the movies, made and designed by The Lego Group.

The Mechno-Chair hasn't been featured in any other LEGO sets, but it *was* made as [an action figure](http://www.rebelscum.com/TLCBD10Sidious.asp), and possibly other toys.

[image]

---

Looking at the [parts list](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=7958-4), I was able to verify you're not missing any! Also, my search technique would have worked even if you weren't 100% certain that it was a *Star Wars* figure or from a LEGO Advent Calendar, as there's a limited number sets with the "Reddish Brown" color of that arm. They key step would have just been figuring out that those leg parts are called arms. (Although, conveniently, [when browsing by color](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?v=1&pg=1&colorPart=88&catType=P), that part is at the top of the list!)

Comment: @Morgan Glad I could help. I've been sorting my LEGO collection for the last month and it's taken over my brain.

Answer (score 69):

The Brickpedia article on the [2011 Star Wars Advent Calendar](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/7958_Star_Wars_Advent_Calendar) says that it is Nute Gunray's walking [Mechno-Chair](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mechno-chair), and seeing it myself, I agree. It was used in *The Phantom Menace* to talk with the hologram of Darth Sidious while walking.

[image: Mechano chair in The Phantom Menace]
[image: Close-up of the mechano chair]

Comment: Very Christmassy!